# How to make an argument optional in PutMapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

How to make an argument optional in PutMapping, if client doesn't pass a Bar it fails with an error. How can I make it optional at the service, method signature given below

```
@PutMapping("/{id}/reject")
public Response<Foo> rejectFoo(@PathVariable("id") String id,
        @RequestBody Bar bar) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "optional" parameter here.

```
@PutMapping("/{id}/reject")
public Response<Foo> rejectFoo(@PathVariable("id") String id,
        @RequestBody Optional<Bar> bar) {
```

For Request, Parameter refer this: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param